# Is there a way to use haveibeenpwned (HIBP) without sending email in clear text?

Tags: security, websecurity

For legal reasons we can't send the email to HIBP in clear text.

Regarding "Domain Search" functionnality, there's no API (as far as I know).
It works by sending you multiple emails, no API, so hard to automate process around that.

I've also read one of Troy's old blog post about a Domain Search callback system he put in place for a specific case : https://www.troyhunt.com/have-i-been-pwned-goes-little-bit/ which looks good but no publicly available (that's my understanding).

So, if HIBP doesn't allow me to do that, I thought of other solutions based on it :

Firefox Monitor and 1pwd :
They use the k-anonymity principle (https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2018/06/25/scanning-breached-accounts-k-anonymity/) which consist to send only a hash of the searched email.
Unfortunately, that functionality is reserved to 1pwd & firefox monitor.

Am I missing a way to interact with HIBP without sending in clear the email ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Mozilla and 1Password use the k-anonymity model described here: https://www.troyhunt.com/were-baking-have-i-been-pwned-into-firefox-and-1password/

The reason I don't make that generally available is that every single k-anonymity search returns multiple results which would make it much easier for a nefarious party to abuse. Domain searches require verification of control at the time of search; an API that didn't require verification would also be open to misuse.

If you'd like to see new features, suggest them here (or vote on them if they already exist): https://haveibeenpwned.uservoice.com/

Comment: Crystal clear, thank you for your answer Troy !

Answer (score 0):

The way I am using k-anonymity via HIBP is to use the following API:

[Searching Pwned Passwords By Range](https://haveibeenpwned.com/API/v3#SearchingPwnedPasswordsByRange)

The easiest and safest way to use this API by writing a small program, where you can enter a password and the rest is done for you.

I programmed a command line tool and named it 'pwnedk'.

The main part of this tool are 3 lines of Haskell code:

```
let
    sha1Hash = hexStringFromPassword sPassword
    (first5FromHash, restFromHash) = Lst.splitAt 5 sha1Hash
    requestURL = 
        "https://api.pwnedpasswords.com/range/" ++ first5FromHash
```

You may take the complete code from here and may build it on your own:

[pwnedk at GitHub](https://github.com/JoergBrueggmann/pwnedk)